# How can I change the Height of PaneToggleButton

Tags: c#, uwp, winui-3

I'm using WinUI 2.8, and I want change Height of PaneToggleButton from my NavigationView.

Can someone help me?

```
<NavigationView PaneTitle="Test" IsPaneToggleButtonVisible="True" IsBackButtonVisible="Visible"></NavigationView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@FrozenAssassine is showing the way to edit the default style of the native `NavigationView` control. Actually, you just need to check the `PaneToggleButtonStyle`. It will be created along with the `NavigationView` style automatically when you follow @FrozenAssassine steps. You could also find the **generic.xaml** (it saves all the default styles for all the native UWP controls.) in the `\(Program Files)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\<SDK version>\Generic folder`

If you are using the `NavigationView` control from the WinUI, you could also check WinUI's  **generic.xaml** here: `C:\Users\(username)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.ui.xaml\2.8.2\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.UI.Xaml\Themes`

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the default Styling of your NavigationView. This can be done by following the steps:

1. Open the Document outline(Ctrl + Alt + D) and your .xaml code file
2. In the document outline, right click on your NavigationView in the document outline and click on "Edit Template" -> "Edit a copy"
3. A window will pop up, and you can give the style a name.
4. The custom style will be added to your code
5. Search for: x:Name="TogglePaneButton"
6. This is the line of the button, you are looking for and you can now change its properties like normal

Here is also the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-control-templates